# Rails REST API and consuming in the same application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, api

I've read many posts about creating and consuming REST APIs but I havent found any useful documentation about how to do it in a single app.

I used to have a completed MVC application working on Rails, but we decided to change it to use a REST API to provide data for other developments, but we are not really sure how to do it. What we did was to create an api/v1/ folder structure with the API controllers inside.

We have a very simple controller to test:

```
class Api::V1::ProductsController < ApplicationController
  def list
    @products = Product.limit(100)
    render json: @products, status: 200
  end
end
```

In my routes file I have the following:

```
namespace :api do
  namespace :v1 do
    scope '/products' do
      get '/list' => 'products#list'
    end
  end
end
```

When I start the server and access http://localhost:3000/api/v1/products/list it works as expected.

But now, I'm trying to consume it from the same application, so I have another ProductsController with the following code:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  include HTTParty 
  base_uri "http://1ocalhost:3000/api/v1/products"     
  format :json

  def index
    @products = self.class.get("/list?category_id=22"))
  end
end
```

When I try to GET that route, it displays the following in the server console:

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-05-08 11:58:30 -0400
Processing by ProductsController#index as HTML
Started GET "/api/v1/products/list?category_id=22" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-05-08 11:58:31 -0400
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 120213ms (ActiveRecord: 2.9ms)

Net::ReadTimeout (Net::ReadTimeout):
```

But after the error is thrown, the request is done correctly in the background.

I would like to know first if this is the right approach and secondly, why am I getting that timeout if I'm in the same server and already tested that getting the API worked.

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 4):

> why am I getting that timeout if I'm in the same server and already tested that getting the API worked.

Exactly **because** you are in the same [single-threaded development] server. You are already in the middle of processing a request. All capacity exhausted.

You *shouldn't* waste resources on making remote calls to itself. What does that accomplish, apart from making your code more resource hungry and brittle? What could've been a simple db request is now the same db request AND an http request.

Querying from the frontend (javascript/browser) is another matter entirely. But on the server - don't do that. If you were worried about code duplication, then extract your query into a QueryObject (or whatever) and use that from both your api controller and app controller.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however you are just answering why i'm getting that error. I still need to know how to call that function without doing an http request (I still need the REST API)

Comment: @Kunstmann: what function? rest api endpoint? Only via http call. Check the last part of the answer, it contains a suggestion that will help you.